# Mock JmsTemplate for integration testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, springmockito

Need to mock JmsTemplate for integration testing in my application.

In my appcontext.xml

```
<bean id="core_connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="core_jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="core_jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="core_connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="core_destination" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="core_destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="core_jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>queue/CoreQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

need to mock the jmstemplete in my testcontext.xml.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: core_jmsTemplate is not used anywhere - is that right? I don't see the need for mocking. Nevertheless, you can use Spring profiles in order to create one or the other bean depending on the active profile.

Comment: i am importing the app-context.xml in test-context.xml.so it need to be initialized.

Answer (score 9):

Or in Spring 4 flavour ;)

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    return Mockito.mock(JmsTemplate.class);
}
```

Exactly as @Stephane said, but without xml.
But still I would recommend you use an embedded broker for your integration tests. As it would allow you to check what exactly is coming to the queue.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
<bean id="core_jmsTemplate" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

You probably need to inject the template and configure the mock (`given(...).willReturn`) in your test.

Comment: I have a problem that Spring creates a proxy the mock like it was a regular bean. In such case `when(..).thenReturn(..)` works fine, but `verify(..)` says that I should execute the method on the mock.

Comment: There's no reason it should create a proxy on that thing unless you have an aspect with a super-wide pointcut in your app. I am afraid you need to figure out why the proxy is created.